# Sum the values from different row in sql

Tags: sql

How to do a sum two value from different row as below:

Table name is account

```
Select * from account
```

The result of the above is:

| Name | Code_led | price. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arsenal | 987 | -100 |
| Arsenal | 654 | -500 |
| Arsenal | 443 | -300 |

I need a query to show me the below

| Name | price |
| --- | --- |
| Arsenal | -600 |

The above result is for example and -600 = -100 with -500 just, i need a query for general because the column (Name) have many data

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag non-involved dbms's.

Comment: That's a legitimate question, @jarlh, although irrelevant in this case; syntax is just the same.

Comment: Please don't post same question multiple times (even with different user id): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76492416/support-for-summation-query

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an ordinary aggregation; column(s) that isn't aggregated has to be part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select name, sum(price) as price
from account
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

ou need to aggregate wth `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Name,SUM(price)
FROM account
GROUP BY Name
```